# Highlight single character in a line for f/F/t/T in vim?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to highlight all characters specified after <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>t</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd> command? Highlighting all the occurrences will accelerate the navigation process via <kbd>;</kbd>/<kbd>,</kbd> after the first match.

Comment: If there are a lot of matches you could use the `/` command instead with `'hlsearch'` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in option for that but you can try one of the many variations of the [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) concept. [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak), for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a plugin called [clever-f](https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim) which highlights the matches after  <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>t</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd>

Example of use after <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
[image: after ta]